# Function spaces and domains

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hi, I was wondering if anyone could help me tackle this linear algebra question?

Currently I have shown that λ1 + λ2 = 0 as when using x=x1

f(x)= 1, g(x)=1 and h(x)=0

then λ1*(f(x))+λ2*(g(x))+λ3*(h(x)) = 0

λ1*(1) + λ2*(1)+λ3*(0) = 0

λ1+λ2=0

Now for b) I have assumed that the way to approach this is to replicate part a) but use x=x2 and then again with x=x3.

Which gives me:
λ1+λ3=0   and -λ2+λ3=0

and then great a matrix from those three conditions:

Row 1 = 1 1 0 | 0      Row 2 = 1 0 1 | 0    Row 3 = 0 -1 1 | 0

Which row reduces to give a row of zeros in row three hence creating a free variable which then tells us that they cannot be linearly independent but in fact linearly dependent.

Am I correct in this method or am I mucking up somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Another way of showing (b) would be to observe that $f-g=h$.